# Best DOM API for Java for HTML

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

What is good DOM api for Java when I need to work with HTML documents which I retrieve using  code with `HttpURLConnection`. I noticed that [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)  except being DOM parser can also do some http connecting. Is there something better or more suitable for more complicated http requests?

Comment: General library recommendations are considered O/T since we don't know your needs. Is there something specific with Jsoup or `HttpURLConnection` that doesn't satisfy your needs? If so, please specify and this will be a valid SO question.

Comment: Needs can be satisfied in different ways. (date time java api vs. Joda time) I am asking for suggestion for the best API as I know there are more of them and was kind of hoping someone who has experience in this sphere can recommend be something here while listening pros and cons in concise way. If question of this type is not valid SO question I can close it, just let me know. Till then I wont bother with reediting my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two sentences, my answer would be: (A) **Don't** mix network connections with DOM parsing in your application design. (B) With [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) you are good to go.

*Some more details follow*:

(A)
I can **not** recommend mixing the two requirements (1) DOM parsing and (2) handling HTTP connections. Of course, I don't know your situation at hand, but you will probably end up with an unclear design which will be difficult to maintain. For instance, if you ever migrate to HTTPS, you could depend on the parser being able to handle it.

(B) That said, if you are working with HTML documents, you will probably be more interested in being able to deal not only with valid XHTML, but also with incomplete markup.

There have been other, related questions on stackoverflow (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183784/which-html-dom-parser-library-for-java-is-best) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java)), which boil down to tools for:

- cleaning up HTML pages to conform to XHTML,
- DOM parsing,
- a combination of both.

The most used tools seem to be

- [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)
- [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) (SAX, not DOM)
- [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) (+ Xerces)

[Here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) is also a list of open source Java HTML parsers, for your convenience.

If you still feel that your parser should handle URL connections, maybe you can specify more details on what you mean by "*more complicated http requests*"?

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your design note. Of course I will decouple the html retrieval from actual parsing. However I dont see a reason why I cannot implement both of these modules of the application with the same API.