# Getting all image tags and changing src in Java

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have created a method that for a given url converts the html into a string. With this string in memory, I would like to find all img tags with a certain data-XXX attribute, extract their src attribute and then change it.

What would be the cleanest way to do this? I have tried XPathReader but it crashes when it finds comments in code... Any other XML parser that would allow me to query for certain attributes without having to go through all tags myself?

Also I've read about regexp but it does not feel right somehow.

Comment: 0
down vote
the best way is to use regex or use scraping api to parse the page using xpath

Comment: The problem with HTML pages is that they are usually NOT valid XML. So every XML parser will give you run-time errors whether or not you have comments in your page. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183784